# Fill rows depending on another row values

Tags: r, row

### The problem is as follows:

I have a data base with 3 columns: **ID / SCORE / ACTION**. I need to identify the fist score different from NA and assign its value (and the action too) to the NA's **before** it. In this case the observations #1 and #2 swould have the same score and action as the observation #3. As well, observations #4, #5 and #6 should take the values of observation #7.

> **ID   SCORE ACTION**
>
> 1 NA NA
>
> 2 NA NA
>
> 3 BB+ T
>
> 4 NA NA
>
> 5 NA NA
>
> 6 NA NA
>
> 7 AAA S
>
> 8 NA NA
>
> **Any ideas? Thanks**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look into `na.locf` from the "zoo" package. In this case, you would want to use the `fromLast` argument:

```
library(zoo)
na.locf(mydf, fromLast=TRUE)
#   ID SCORE ACTION
# 1  1   BB+      T
# 2  2   BB+      T
# 3  3   BB+      T
# 4  4   AAA      S
# 5  5   AAA      S
# 6  6   AAA      S
# 7  7   AAA      S
# 8  8  <NA>   <NA>
```